# How to avoid data trimming while formatting file in unix

Tags: text-formatting

I have a file in below format

```
A           |b -c          |   c      |  d  -c | | |
```

And I need to format the above file like below

```
A|b -c|c|d  -c|||
```

Please note, I don't want to remove the space from data.I just want to remove the extra space before the data terminator i.e | (pipe).

Comment: Is it fair to say that you now want to remove space from *after* the pipe as well?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `sed` to say "replace one or more spaces followed by a pipe with a pipe" -- and do that for every occurrence of those spaces & pipes:

```
sed  's/  *|/|/g' < input > output
```

To also remove spaces *after* the pipe:

```
sed  's/  *|/|/g; s/|  */|/g' < input > output
```

Comment: what If I want to remove extra spaces before pipe | too..

Comment: doesn't the above remove extra spaces before the pipe?

Comment: No..it didn't remove

Comment: Do you have two spaces between the first slash and the asterisk?

Comment: Yes there are 2 spaces.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the input, command, and output? Comments have limited formatting capabilities. Thank you!

Comment: changed the input format in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Awk, setting the input field separator to a pipe surrounded by any amount of whitespace and the output field separator to just a pipe:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]*\\|[ \t]*"; OFS="|"} {$1=$1} 1' file
```